# jqgrid width increase issue on reload

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am reloading a JQGrid on a button click, but on each click, its width is getting increased and putting the horizontal scroll bar.How can i fix the width to 100% of browser width even when its reload.
Here is my Code

```
    jQuery("#enhDg").jqGrid({
    url:"/ItLabourEffort/effort/grid/enhView",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Customer/Capibility Name','Completed-FYTD','In Progress','In Queue','Customer'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'capabilityName',index:'capabilityName' ,width:'500',summaryType:'count', summaryTpl : 'Total Count:  {0}', align: 'center'},
        {name:'completedFYTD',index:'completedFYTD', align:'center', sorttype:'number',summaryType:'sum' ,width:'300'},
        {name:'inProgress',index:'inProgress', align:'center',sorttype:'number',summaryType:'sum',width:'300'},
        {name:'queue',index:'queue', align:'center',width:'250',summaryType:'sum'},
        {name:'customerName',index:'customerName' ,width:'550',summaryType:'count'}

    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    height:$("#container").height(),
    sortname: 'invdate',
    viewrecords: true,
    width: '100%',
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Enhancement Forecast View",
    grouping: true,
    groupingView : {
        groupField : ['customerName'],
        groupColumnShow : [true],
        groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
        groupCollapse : false,
        loadonce:true,
        groupOrder: ['asc'],
        groupSummary : [true],
        showSummaryOnHide: true,
        groupDataSorted : true
    },
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true,

});
jQuery("#enhDg").jqGrid('navGrid','#enhDg',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});
jQuery("#enhDg").jqGrid('hideCol','customerName');
$('#timeSelectorRadio input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    jQuery("#enhDg").jqGrid().setGridParam(
            {
                datatype:'json', 
                url : "/ItLabourEffort/effort/grid/enhView2"
            }
        ).trigger("reloadGrid");
    jQuery("#enhDg").jqGrid('hideCol','customerName');

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  width: '100%', to width: auto, and try this

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $("#enhDg").setGridWidth($('#grid_container').width() - 30, true);
}).trigger('resize');
```

and your html may looks like

```
<div id="grid_container" style="width: 100%;">
<table id="enhDg">
    <tr>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this helps..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but now it adds horizontal scroll bar in JQgrid. It improves as in previous case, it used to go out of browser window and was adding scroll bar in browser.

Comment: @gunjan You are welcome. Remove the width parameters from your colmodel. Which browser you are working? If it is **chrome** there will be default horizontal scrollbar, but still you can hide using css given below in your html file.  `th.ui-th-column div {
 white-space: normal !important;
 height: auto !important;
 padding: 2px;
}

.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
 white-space: normal !important;
 height: auto;
 vertical-align: text-top;
 padding-top: 2px;
}`

Comment: Thanks, i use Chrome, but would like to see the same behavior on Safari, IE and firefox. Though above CSS works.

Comment: @gunjan Glad to help you. I haven't checked those css in safari. Can you post your json data (may be sample)? so that i could check.

Comment: Here is the JSON:   {"total":1,"page":1,"records":9,"rows":[{"customerName":"Digital Marketing","capabilityName":"24X7 Operation","completedFYTD":6,"inProgress":0,"queue":4},{"customerName":"Digital Marketing","capabilityName":"Arch and Design","completedFYTD":12,"inProgress":4,"queue":4},{"customerName":"Digital Marketing","capabilityName":"Billing","completedFYTD":26,"inProgress":45,"queue":4}]}